# Bash command unable to read variable argument

Tags: linux, bash

Here is my program

```
#!/bin/bash

command="LVDS-1 --auto --right-of HDMI-1"
main_mon="LVDS-1"
position="--right-of"
aux_mon="HDMI-1"


# Don't work
# warning: output LVDS-1 --auto --right-of HDMI-1 not found; ignoring
xrandr --output "$command"

# Works
xrandr --output "$main_mon" --auto "$position" "$aux_mon"
```

As you can see if i "split" `command` into several variables `xrandr` is able to run the command, otherwise it don't.

The output error is: `warning: output LVDS-1 --auto --right-of HDMI-1 not found; ignoring` when using `$command`

Comment: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/108618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xrandr` expects each argument to be a separate word. Read about "word splitting" in `man bash`.

To only use one variable, you can use an array in bash:

```
#! /bin/bash
args=( --output LVDS-1 --auto --right-of HDMI-1 )
xrandr "${args[@]}"
```